# How to query in mogodb on date on a epoch timestamp filed

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a collection name loan, and the details are as follow -

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5d34acadcaef727889922'),
 'created_by': 'tom',
 'created_on': 1563733165768,
 'name': 'CITI',
 'source': 'generic',
}
```

the `created_on` is saving as epoch format, - `1563733165768 (21 July 2019 23:49:25.768),`

I want to query with - `1563647400000 (21 July 2019 00:00:00)`

As both timestamp date is same, So How to query on date and get result in pymongo ?

Answer (score 0):

the epoch format is just an integer number for mongodb, not an actual datetime object. So you need to first convert your datetime object into epoch number and then do a greater than query

```
db.loan.find({'created_on': {'$gte': 1563647400000}})
```

You can convert the datetime into epoch by following these steps

```
import datetime as datetime_lib
epoch = datetime_lib.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
timestamp = (datetime_obj - epoch).total_seconds() * 1000
```